# how to make form validation working when submitting to another page

Tags: php, forms, validation

Validation doesn't work on my form
I want validation to run in my form and show errors

here's my code for Contact Form.php

```
<p><span class="error"> * required field(s)</span></p>
<form action="user_input.php" method="post">
<table>
    <tr>
    <td><label>Name: <span class="error"> *<?php echo $nameErr;?> </span></label></td></tr>
        <td><input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Type your name" value="<?php echo $name;?>"></td>
    <tr><td><label>Email: <span class="error"> *<?php echo $emailErr;?> </span></label></td></tr>
        <td><input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Type your email" value="<?php echo $email;?>"></td>
    <tr><td><label>Address: <span class="optional"> Optional</span></label></td></tr>
        <td><input name="address" type="text" placeholder="Type your location" value="<?php echo $address;?>"></td>
    <tr><td><label>Phone: <span class="error"> * <?php echo $phoneErr;?></span></label></td></tr>
        <td><input name="phone" type="tel" placeholder="Type your phone number" value="<?php echo $phone;?>"></td>
    <tr><td><label>Message: <span class="error"> * <?php echo $messageErr;?> </span></label></td></tr>
        <td><textarea name="message" row="5" cols="40" placeholder="Type your message here" value="<?php echo $message;?>"></textarea></td>
        </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

and my code for user_input.php

```
<?php

$nameErr = $emailErr = $addressErr = $phoneErr = $messageErr = "";
$name = $email = $address = $phone = $message = "";

    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if(empty($_POST["name"])) {
        $nameErr = "Name required";
        header("location: contact_form.php");
    } else {
        $name = input($_POST["name"]);
    }

    if(empty($_POST["email"])) {
        $emailErr = "Email required";
        header("location: contact_form.php");
    } else {
        $email = input($_POST["email"]);
        // check if email is valid
        if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $emailErr = "Invalid email";
            header("location: contact_form.php");
        }
    }

    if(empty($_POST["address"])) {
        $addressErr = "Invalid Address";
        header("location: contact_form.php");
    } else {
        $address = input($_POST["address"]);
    }

    if(empty($_POST["phone"])) {
        $phoneErr = "Phone number required";
        header("location: contact_form.php");
    } else {
        $phone = input($_POST["phone"]);
        if(!preg_match("/^[0-9]+$/", $phone) || strlen($phone) > 20) {
            $phoneErr = "Invalid phone number";
            header("location: contact_form.php");
        }
    }
    if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
        $messageErr = "Message required";
        header("location: contact_form.php");
    } else {
        $message = input($_POST["message"]);
    }
}
```

I don't know where I have errors it should be able to output errors and validating.

I want only php not jquery or javascript

Comment: there is no need to redirect everytime it will automatic refresh your page

Comment: as mentioned in my answer, people usually separate the display and php logic as a result, it would be easy to manage both the pages.

Comment: @Amit: I didnt find your answer yet, well if you use header than how can you get the $_POST values after redirection???

Answer (score 1):

You should store the error messages in a session.

What you do now is setting a variable that is limited to the runtime. As soon as the user changes the page (what he does with location header) they will be flushed. Sessions are not flushed and can be used on per user basis and will be viable for 30 minutes default I think (config can change the duration)

Just add errors like

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['errors'][] = 'Name required';
```

On the page you can now access them like `foreach($_SESSION['errors'] as $error){...` and then delete them `unset($_SESSION['errors']);`

Comment: where should I put this code?
in contact_form.php or user_input.php?

Comment: The session start code is for user_input.php the foreach is for the contact_form.php. One is adding errors to a list. The other one is diplaying and clearing the list. Note that session_start is only needed one time at the beginning of both files and unset one time at the end of the foreach (after it)

Comment: can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `header()` function from error condition and also use an `array` for storing your errors. instead of multiple variables.

Comment: Did you removed header location?  @AppDevelopment